# jquery mouseover

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a button on my asp.net page and I am using ajax jquery to create a mouseover effect.I want to show alert on mouse over. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#myButtonId').mouseover(function() {
  alert('Hello World!');
});
```

Comment: Does you button have an id of 'myButtonId'? You also have to enclose the function in the usual $(document).ready(function() { // function goes here }); block so the selector is registered.

Comment: yes it is in document.ready and i have named button as myButtonId. when I bring mouse, I get alert. What I want is to that jquery automatically do a mouseover as we use myButtonId.click

Comment: Also you say you are using 'ajax jquery' - if the button html is being loaded into the page as part of an ajax request then you will need to add the function into the success handler of the ajax call.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand "What I want is to that jquery automatically do a mouseover as we use myButtonId.click". If you want to fire the mouseover event when the user clicks the button (which seems an odd way to go about things) take a look at the .trigger function in jquery.

Comment: @Mark, I am sorry its just jquery and I am creating jquery Qunit test. I want to perform mouseover and then show alert in qUNit after mouseover.

Comment: It may be worth posting a new question then and mention qUnit so that the answer is captured for this question which is slightly different to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery in the head section of your HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Then in your HTML, you make the button.

```
<button id="someButton">Mouse over me!</button>
```

And you attach the mouseover event helper when everything is completed loading.

```
<script>
// The $ function is used as short-hand for document.ready function.
// http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/
$(function() {
    $("button#someButton").mouseover(function() {
        alert("Hello world");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: HI Greg: I want to use it with asp.net button

Comment: Also, I want mouseover to happen automatically. I dont want that an alert is shown when user mouseover the button. Rather I want to trigger mouseover automatically

Comment: Well in that case just use `alert()` and forget the mouse event totally